# Query multiple partitioned tables

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, partitioning

I am working on partitioned tables(snapshots) of different time ranges:

*1st input table:*

| Case | Stage | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2022-08-01 |
| B | 1 | 2022-08-01 |
| C | 2 | 2022-08-01 |

*2nd Input Table:*

| Case | Stage | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2022-08-03 |
| B | 2 | 2022-08-03 |
| C | 2 | 2022-08-03 |

*3rd Input Table:*

| Case | Stage | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 2022-08-04 |
| B | 2 | 2022-08-04 |
| C | 2 | 2022-08-04 |

*Result Expected:*

| Case | Date |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2022-08-03 |
| A | 2022-08-04 |

*Explaination*:
I was hoping to fetch the first time a *case* moves from *one stage to the other*.
So,

1. B shifted from stage 1 to 2 from 1 Aug 2022 -> 3 Aug 2022 while the other 2 cases A and C didnt shift stage.
2. A moved from Stage 1 to Stage 2 from Aug 1 -> Aug 4, hence its in the output as well.

*Challenge faced*:
Every case can have a different date to move from Stage 1. So its not necessary that 2nd input table might apply for all cases.
e.g - Case A moves out from Stage 1 -> Stage 2 on 4th august, that would be a part of the output too.

Comment: Have you tried any queries for this?

Comment: Hi, I had tried joining the two tables on conditions i.e table1.case=table2.case and table1.stage<table2.stage but thats not going to work, as I can have other date partitioned tables where Case moved from 1 stage to other. Thanks for the asking, I have made the edit to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
with unioned as (
SELECT * FROM t1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t3
)

SELECT `Case`
  , min(date) as Date
from unioned
group by `Case`, Stage
qualify row_number() over (PARTITION BY `Case` ORDER BY Stage) = 2
```

It produces the following results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch Daniel, gives the expected output. Appreciate it!